# Looping between child nodes in firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a fantasy web-application of about 50 players. Below is a mock database for my web app:

```
Users {
   John: {
       Selection: [1,2,3]
   },
   Mark: {
       Selection: [1,2,4]
   } 
}

Players {
1: {
    name: 'Messi',
    agility: 90
},
2: {
    name: 'Beckham',
    agility: 54
},
3: {
    name: 'Rooney',
    agility: 10
},
4: {
    name: 'Neymar',
    agility: 84
}
}
```

After the client has made their selection as "Mark" and "John" have done in the example, considering that the "Users" node and the "Players" node are different child nodes in the database tree, is there a way to say loop through the players array using the respective user's selection array?

If so, can this looping result in each client's selections being reflected in  on the client-side

The code for each client's selection is as follows:

```
  var ref = firebase.database().ref("players");
  var ref3 = firebase.database().ref("users").child(uid).child("total");

  $scope.players = $firebaseArray(ref);
  $scope.selected = $firebaseArray(ref3);
```

"ref" is the array of 50 players in the firebase database while "ref3" is the 6-player array created by the client.

Is there a way to map or loop over the players array in search of the 6 selected players in the "ref3" arrray?

Answer (score 0):

Mapping selection `id`s to `players` can be done.

```
function getSelectedPlayers(selection, players, meta) {
    return selection.map((id) => { ...meta, player: players[id] });
}
```

Say, we wanted to get John's selected players. We can write:

```
getSelectedPlayers(Users.John.Selection, Players, { uid: 'l30n4rd0' });
```

Comment: thanks. Would the function not have to account for each client's uid? so that each client's uid maps to specific players depending on who they select?

Comment: The function here only cares about the selection. If you wanted to have more information returned in the mapped data, you can modify the functional predicate to take extra arguments and return that in the object term.

Comment: I have edited the question a bit. Would mapping still work as edited? I tried mapping the selected array using the players array but it didn't work.